# Add custom class to md-tooltip

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm new to angular md, so this is probably a stupid question, but I can't figure it out. I want to add a class "leadTimeTooltip" to md-tooltip, and style it in css file like this, but it's not working:

```css
.leadTimeTooltip{
    height: auto !important;
    width:auto !important;
    white-space: inherit !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    background-color: rgba(247,247,247,0.85);
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<md-tooltip md-delay="600" class="leadTimeTooltip">
  <pre class="leadTimePre">{{partVm.leadTimeExplanation}}</pre>
</md-tooltip>
```

However the following works:

```css
md-tooltip ._md-content {
...
}
```

But I don't want to style all tooltips, just the ones with leadTimeTooltip class, so I tried the following, not working:

```css
md-tooltip ._md-content .leadTimeTooltip{
...
}
```

Anyone knows what I do wrong? Pls help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `pre` tag have the md-tooltip inside div or button or span element (not `p`) component. Then your template can be:

```
<div>Hover over me
    <md-tooltip md-delay="600" class="leadTimeTooltip">
      <pre class="leadTimePre">{{tooltipContent}}</pre>
    </md-tooltip> 
</div>
```

Here's link for working plunker to add css properties to content of specific tooltip: https://plnkr.co/edit/R2iIr9bMlS5nONpJuRc4?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still does't work. I reproduced the problem based on your plunker, I changed angular version, but that's not the issue, you can comment and uncomment css block to see my problem. https://plnkr.co/edit/RMSaHiqaJm8jneag4cND?p=preview

Comment: Hey I think you've made type of the class you applied to pre tag. It's leadTimePre but inside style.css file you're assigning properties to 'md-tooltip .md-content .leadTimeTooltip' instead it should be 'md-tooltip .md-content .leadTimePre'. Here's working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/EZZ2QXSyLdueEhIrCqT0?p=preview